# minitoc Errors (potential clashes with other packages?)

Tags: table-of-contents, books, minitoc

I want to insert chapter content for my thesis by using minitoc package. It seems working on its own. However, if I add other packages for other purposes, then it does not work and I keep getting the following error:

! Undefined control sequence.
\label #1->\@bsphack \begingroup \def \label@name

Here is my code. I guess there might be some clashes between packages. However, I do not know whether that is the case or what the clashes are. Is there an easy fix, please? In addition, how to modify the code for \include{} method in order to add mini content, please? Thank you!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}

  \newcommand{\blanknonumber}{\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}}

  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{float}  

  % header and footer  
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \fancyhead[ro, le]{}
  \fancyhead[lo]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
  \fancyhead[re]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
  \pagestyle{fancy} % Change page style to fancy
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}

  % font
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

  % chapter titles
  \usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}

  % hyper links
  \usepackage{hyperref}

  % author-date reference
  \usepackage{natbib}

  % enumeration
  \usepackage{enumitem}

  % needed for chapter toc
  \usepackage{minitoc}  

\begin{document}

  \frontmatter

  \include{titlepage}\blanknonumber
  \dominitoc
  \tableofcontents\blanknonumber

  \mainmatter

  \include{chapter1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The clash is with `fncychap` package

Comment: @karlkoeller Is there a way to get around this, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option `Glenn` for the package `fncychap` issues the command

```
\ChTitleUpperCase
```

to make the title of the chapter in upper case letters. This is incompatible with the `minitoc` package.

A solution is to issue

```
\ChTitleAsIs
```

just before loading `fncychap`. The drawback is that you will have to manually uppercase your chapter titles.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}

  \newcommand{\blanknonumber}{\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}}

  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{float}

  % header and footer
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \fancyhead[ro, le]{}
  \fancyhead[lo]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
  \fancyhead[re]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
  \pagestyle{fancy} % Change page style to fancy
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}

  % font
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

  % chapter titles
  \usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
  \ChTitleAsIs

  % hyper links
  \usepackage{hyperref}

  % author-date reference
  \usepackage{natbib}

  % enumeration
  \usepackage{enumitem}

  % needed for chapter toc
  \usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

  \frontmatter

  \chapter{titlepage}\blanknonumber
  \dominitoc
  \tableofcontents\blanknonumber

  \mainmatter

  \chapter{chapter1}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: The best option is avoiding `fncychap`.